# Generate pdf through microsoft word

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

I have a Microsoft word document with 58 pages when I generate pdf file with word itself or doPDF or other softwares, they generate pdf file with 61 pages. How can I solve this problem.
My document written in Persian language.

Answer (score 1):

Word loves to reformat the document whenever something is changed in the printer settings (such as selecting another printer). You might make sure that you have the printer driver used for doPDF active when you edit the document, and invoke the Print command.

You may also make sure that the page sizes selected in the print dialog correspond to the one of the document.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but in the save as pdf of word there isn't print paper size and in dopdf I several time change paper size but automatically it goes to it's default(letter)

Answer (score 0):

You can also, make sure that you have written the document using word's ability to end (break pages) that way you will make sure that the pages you have are not moving, especially the figures.

Comment: Thanks, but when I use break page my page configuration change, I don't know why?

Comment: You can use break continuous, this will not alter your structure a lot. And perhaps think of "anchoring" your figures at the locations you have placed them